# I currently program excusively in AS3. How can I utilize the new flash.ui:MouseCursorData in cs4?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, mouse, flash-cs4

I've seen examples of the new mouse cursor code done after flash 10.2 and was wondering if there is any way I can set it up and use it in cs4 for exclusively AS3 programs.

Comment: Problem solved by upgrading to Flash CS5.5

Answer (score 0):

MouseCursorData can be set is AS 3 . You can download the new SDK from opensource.adobe.com . Use that sdk for your project.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MouseCursorData.html